# Rich text on pocket.outlook?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, outlook

On desktop outlook, the "body" property of tasks and calendar entries may contain rich text (formatting, links, etc). However, when using pocket.outlook on WM, I am only able to access a "plain text" version of the text that is stored. Is there a way to obtain it in "rich text" format?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I googled around and came across [this](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/18_2005_2_0_0_49655/RichTextBox-Control-in-net-Compact-Framework.htm), as per the suggestion, to use the InkX control instead of RichTextBox, but AFAIK and from prior experience, there is no RichTextBox control available for the Compact Framework. [Here](http://forums.thoughtsmedia.com/f415/looking-alternative-richtextbox-68261.html)'s another suggestion, to use Html. Also [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.compactframework/2005-02/0166.html) suggests the InkX which is found in the Smart Device Framework community edition [here](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx). In fact, you might just be able to parse the RTF and spit out the HTML equivalent, see here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx) on this, and [NRtfTree](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx) (it may be recompiled for the Compact Framework, and use the WebBrowser control to show the Html version of the message)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.